# How to Code Outer Product of a Set of Elements in Julia?

Tags: tuples, julia, outer-product

**Permutations of a Set of Elements**

I have a Julia snippet which generates all possible 4-tuples with 3 possible elements in each slot:

```
julia> collect(Iterators.product(ntuple(_ -> 1:3, 4)...))
3×3×3×3 Array{NTuple{4, Int64}, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 (1, 1, 1, 1)  (1, 2, 1, 1)  (1, 3, 1, 1)
 (2, 1, 1, 1)  (2, 2, 1, 1)  (2, 3, 1, 1)
 (3, 1, 1, 1)  (3, 2, 1, 1)  (3, 3, 1, 1)

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 (1, 1, 2, 1)  (1, 2, 2, 1)  (1, 3, 2, 1)
 (2, 1, 2, 1)  (2, 2, 2, 1)  (2, 3, 2, 1)
 (3, 1, 2, 1)  (3, 2, 2, 1)  (3, 3, 2, 1)

[:, :, 3, 1] =
 (1, 1, 3, 1)  (1, 2, 3, 1)  (1, 3, 3, 1)
 (2, 1, 3, 1)  (2, 2, 3, 1)  (2, 3, 3, 1)
 (3, 1, 3, 1)  (3, 2, 3, 1)  (3, 3, 3, 1)

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 (1, 1, 1, 2)  (1, 2, 1, 2)  (1, 3, 1, 2)
 (2, 1, 1, 2)  (2, 2, 1, 2)  (2, 3, 1, 2)
 (3, 1, 1, 2)  (3, 2, 1, 2)  (3, 3, 1, 2)
...
```

**Question**

How do I modify this code so that instead of using a range `1:3` for the elements, I select elements out of an array, say `[1,5]`, or a set `Set([1,5])`, with only 2 possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
julia> original = collect(Iterators.product(ntuple(_ -> [1,5], 4)...))
2×2×2×2 Array{NTuple{4, Int64}, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 (1, 1, 1, 1)  (1, 5, 1, 1)
 (5, 1, 1, 1)  (5, 5, 1, 1)

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 (1, 1, 5, 1)  (1, 5, 5, 1)
 (5, 1, 5, 1)  (5, 5, 5, 1)

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 (1, 1, 1, 5)  (1, 5, 1, 5)
 (5, 1, 1, 5)  (5, 5, 1, 5)

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 (1, 1, 5, 5)  (1, 5, 5, 5)
 (5, 1, 5, 5)  (5, 5, 5, 5)

julia> flattened = [original...]
16-element Vector{NTuple{4, Int64}}:
 (1, 1, 1, 1)
 (5, 1, 1, 1)
 (1, 5, 1, 1)
 (5, 5, 1, 1)
 (1, 1, 5, 1)
 (5, 1, 5, 1)
 (1, 5, 5, 1)
 (5, 5, 5, 1)
 (1, 1, 1, 5)
 (5, 1, 1, 5)
 (1, 5, 1, 5)
 (5, 5, 1, 5)
 (1, 1, 5, 5)
 (5, 1, 5, 5)
 (1, 5, 5, 5)
 (5, 5, 5, 5)
```

So, it's possible to simply substitute an array or set for the iterator. Afterwards, you can [flatten the resulting matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61797748/18431399) with the [splat operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...).

Additionally, here is how elements can be accessed in the form `A[i,j]` using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129125/nested-list-comprehensions-in-julia):

```
julia> original  =  collect(Iterators.product(ntuple(_ -> 1:3, 4)...));
julia> newMatrix = [original[:,:,a,b] for a in 1:3, b in 1:3];

julia> newMatrix[2,3]
3×3 Matrix{NTuple{4, Int64}}:
 (1, 1, 2, 3)  (1, 2, 2, 3)  (1, 3, 2, 3)
 (2, 1, 2, 3)  (2, 2, 2, 3)  (2, 3, 2, 3)
 (3, 1, 2, 3)  (3, 2, 2, 3)  (3, 3, 2, 3)

julia> typeof(newMatrix)
Matrix{Matrix{NTuple{4, Int64}}} (alias for Array{Array{NTuple{4, Int64}, 2}, 2})
```

Comment: Total modification of the code is fine, but would like it to keep it a one liner.  Also, maybe I wasn't clear enough - in place of permuting 3 elements `1:3`, I'm looking to permute two elements `[1,5]`.